# Как удалить второй переход на новую строку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, строки

Как можно удалить `\n` из строки символов на определённой позиции, то-есть так чтобы не исчезли остальные `\n`?

```py
mystr = 'Привет \nмир\n!'
```

Использовал метод `re.sub(r'\n','',mystr)` , но он не подходит т.к. удаляет все `\n`  из строки

Как добиться вывода

```
Привет 
мир!
```

наиболее простым способом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Help on built-in function rpartition:

rpartition(sep, /) method of builtins.str instance
    Partition the string into three parts using the given separator.

    This will search for the separator in the string, starting at the end. If
    the separator is found, returns a 3-tuple containing the part before the
    separator, the separator itself, and the part after it.

    If the separator is not found, returns a 3-tuple containing two empty strings
    and the original string.
```

---

```py
mystr = 'Привет \nмир\n!'
partition = mystr.rpartition("\n")
new_mystr = partition[0] + partition[2]
print(repr(new_mystr))
```

Или короче:

```py
mystr = 'Привет \nмир\n!'
new_mystr = "".join(mystr.rpartition("\n")[::2])
print(repr(new_mystr))
```

### Вывод:

```
'Привет \nмир!'
```

---

На основе [ответа на en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3675423/10941639).